# Aggregating JMX

Tags: java, jmx, aggregation, jconsole

In a scenario where we have several JVMs, each running it's JMX agent with its own MBeanServer.
What's the best way to aggregate all these MBeans in these different MBeanServers into one, so that we can connect a single JConsole or other client to the aggregation in order to monitor all MBeans.

Best,
Will

Answer (score 0):

You could try Spring's JMX support: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jmx.html#jmx-proxy